# C: How to send a client message sent to a server to all clients?

Tags: c, sockets

Right now, my code allows multiple clients to connect to the server and sent messages to the server, which are then sent back only to the client that sent it. I'm stuck trying to figure out how to get the server to send received messages to all clients.

I have considered storing the sd's in an array and then write to each sd, but I first printed the sd and it is always the same number (4), so I'm not sure what I should do

My current code:

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "networking.h"

void process( char * s );
void sub_server( int sd );

int main() {

  int sd, connection;

  sd = server_setup();

  while (1) {

    connection = server_connect( sd );

    int f = fork();
    if ( f == 0 ) {

      close(sd);
      sub_server( connection );

      exit(0);
    }
    else {
      close( connection );
    }
  }
  return 0;
}


void sub_server( int sd ) {

  char buffer[MESSAGE_BUFFER_SIZE];
  while (read( sd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) )) {

    printf("[SERVER %d] received: %s\n", getpid(), buffer );
    process( buffer );
    write( sd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));    
  }

}
void process( char * s ) {

  while ( *s ) {
    *s = (*s - 'a' + 13) % 26 + 'a';
    s++;
  }
}
```

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "networking.h"

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

  char *host;
  if (argc != 2 ) {
    printf("host not specified, conneting to 127.0.0.1\n");
    host = "127.0.0.1";
  }
  else
    host = argv[1];

  int sd;

  sd = client_connect( host );

  char buffer[MESSAGE_BUFFER_SIZE];

  while (1) {
    printf("enter message: ");
    fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin );
    char *p = strchr(buffer, '\n');
    *p = 0;

    write( sd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) );
    read( sd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) );
    printf( "received: %s\n", buffer );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

networking.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void error_check( int i, char *s ) {
  if ( i < 0 ) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
    printf("[%s] error %d: %s\n", s, errno, strerror(errno) );
    exit(1);
  }
}

int server_setup() {

  int sd;
  int i;

  sd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
  error_check( sd, "server socket" );

  struct sockaddr_in sock;
  sock.sin_family = AF_INET;
  sock.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  sock.sin_port = htons(9001);
  i = bind( sd, (struct sockaddr *)&sock, sizeof(sock) );
  error_check( i, "server bind" );

  return sd;
}

int server_connect(int sd) {
  int connection, i;

  i = listen(sd, 1);
  error_check( i, "server listen" );

  struct sockaddr_in sock1;
  unsigned int sock1_len = sizeof(sock1);
  connection = accept( sd, (struct sockaddr *)&sock1, &sock1_len );
  error_check( connection, "server accept" );

  printf("[server] connected to %s\n", inet_ntoa( sock1.sin_addr ) );

  return connection;
}


int client_connect( char *host ) {
  int sd, i;

  sd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
  error_check( sd, "client socket" );

  struct sockaddr_in sock;
  sock.sin_family = AF_INET;
  inet_aton( host, &(sock.sin_addr));
  sock.sin_port = htons(9001);

  printf("[client] connecting to: %s\n", host );
  i = connect( sd, (struct sockaddr *)&sock, sizeof(sock) );
  error_check( i, "client connect");

  return sd;
}
```

Assistance and explanations are much appreciated (I'm also new to C, so please try to explain)

Comment: You need to share to every subserver a list of all clients... Don't use fork, but threads.

Comment: which part of the code you were printing the `sd` and was seeing 4 every time?